# Is it possible to get the set of candidate evicted keys in Caffeine?

Tags: java, caching, akka, caffeine

I am attempting to use a cache to maintain a list of routable servers based on request type.

```
LoadingCache<Request, ActorRef> serversByRequestType = Caffeine.newBuilder()
  .writer(new CacheWriter<RequestType, ActorRef>() {

    @Override public void write(RequestType req, ActorRef server) {
      // We need to handle this type of request now.
      //
      server.tell(StartUp(req))
    }

    @Override public void delete(RequestType req, ActorRef server, RemovalCause cause) {
      // This req type can no longer be handled, so remove from
      // routable servers.
      //
      server.tell(ShutDown(req))
    }

  })
  .build();
```

In the case that I can have no more than `n` servers up, it is important to synchronize the deletion (and therefore shut down) of a server from the cache followed by the addition (and therefore spin-up) of *the same* server in the cache (i.e., changing the traffic the server can handle).

In the above code, there's no way to do this without blocking.

In an ideal world, deletion must happen before addition in a cache, so I could asynchronously shut down the server and wait for a `ShutdownServer` event... but there's no way to receive this signal from within the `write` method, which necessarily needs to know when to start. In other words, I'd like to send a `SwitchServerTraffic(from: RequestType, to: RequestType)` to the `server`, where `from` will be the evicted key and `to` will be the added key.

If I had access to the candidate eviction set: when a request comes in, if its type is not in the cache and the cache is at capacity, I can select an element from the eviction set and shut down its server, then add the request type to the cache synchronously à la Akka.

Is there a way to get access to the candidate eviction set in Caffeine? If not, is there another way to frame this problem that obviates it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a guess of the items in eviction order, but this will not be guaranteed. The policy is non-deterministic and that probabilistic helps protect against HashDoS attacks. In general low-level details of the eviction policy are not exposed to allow for algorithmic improvements.

```
Map<K, V> coldest = cache.policy().eviction().get().coldest(count);
```

If deletion occurred prior to eviction would either require that all writes are guarded by an exclusive lock or the policy can be evaluated concurrently. The former would be a bottleneck and the latter would result in a significantly worse hit rate (e.g. by using random sampling). The cache instead uses a record & replay strategy with intermediate buffers, which absorbs most of the penalties of being concurrent.

By default eviction is performed asynchronously to user-facing calls, so most calls to `CacheWriter#delete` will be hidden. However, if that call is expensive then it delays the eviction of the next item.

Unfortunately its difficult to offer advice without being in your shoes, as your scenario has unique constraints to your needs. You might find the compute methods in `Cache.asMap()` useful for whatever the solution ends up looking like.

Comment: Accepting for the immediate answer, upvoting for the caveats and tips. Cheers, Ben.

Comment: Hopefully someone has a better one to solve your problem, and you can award them :)

Comment: It's a tough problem! If I come up with a nice solution, I'll try to share.